# Losing Events during RxJava subscribeOn()

Tags: android, rx-java2, mosby

I got the following code using Mosby.

Fragment:

```
@Override
public Observable<CardInfo> loadCardIntent() {
    return Observable.just(new CardInfo(cardselected, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext())
            .getBoolean(PreferencesVariables.SHOW_BACK_CARD.toString(), false)))
            //.delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .doOnNext(showBack -> Log.d(TAG, "Show card back: " + showBack));
 }

@Override
 public Observable<CardInfo> loadFrontIntent() {
        return RxView.clicks(cardBackImageView)
                .map(showFront -> new CardInfo(cardselected, false))
                .doOnNext(showFront -> Log.d(TAG, "Show card front"));
}

@Override
public Observable<Boolean> hideCardIntent() {
        return clicks(cardFrontImageView)
                .map(ignored -> true)
                .doOnNext(close -> Log.d(TAG, "Close card activity"));
}
```

Presenter:

```
@Override
    protected void bindIntents() {

        Observable<CardViewState> showSelectedCard = intent(CardView::loadCardIntent)
                .switchMap(cardInfo -> interactor.getCard(cardInfo))
                .doOnError(error -> System.out.print(error.getMessage()));

        Observable<CardViewState> showFront = intent(CardView::loadFrontIntent)
                .switchMap(cardInfo -> interactor.getCard(cardInfo))
                .doOnError(error -> System.out.print(error.getMessage()));

        Observable<CardViewState> hideCard = intent(CardView::hideCardIntent)
                .switchMap(ignored -> interactor.hideCard());

        Observable<CardViewState> intents = Observable.merge(showSelectedCard, showFront, hideCard)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        subscribeViewState(intents, CardView::render);
    }
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void render(CardViewState viewState) {
    if (viewState instanceof CardViewState.CardBackState) {
        renderCard(R.raw.planningpoker_rueckseite, cardBackImageView);
        renderCard(((CardViewState.CardBackState) viewState).card, cardFrontImageView);
        showCardBack();
    } else if (viewState instanceof CardViewState.CardFrontState) {
        renderCard(R.raw.planningpoker_rueckseite, cardBackImageView);
        renderCard(((CardViewState.CardFrontState) viewState).card, cardFrontImageView);
        showCardFront();
    } else if (viewState instanceof CardViewState.CardCloseState) {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

Interactor:

```
Observable<CardViewState> getCard(CardInfo cardInfo) {
    return cardInfo.showBack ? Observable.just(new CardViewState.CardBackState(CARDS[cardInfo.card])) :
            Observable.just(new CardViewState.CardFrontState(CARDS[cardInfo.card]));
}

Observable<CardViewState> hideCard() {
    return Observable.just(new CardViewState.CardCloseState());
}
```

Without the delay in `loadCardIntent()` the `render()`-method does not get triggered with the CardBackState. But I don't want to use a arbitrary delay to ensure the right methods get triggered.
Is there any other way to ensure that all events get emitted?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: could you share the code of your interactor?

Comment: @sockeqwe I added a the part of interactor which is called. It only takes a value from an array which is more or less an integer resource assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for now is to use `Schedulers.trampoline()`. It is not ideal and in no way sufficient but it allows me to get rid of the delay that is more of a hassle.

The problem that `Schedulers.trampoline()` seem to be solving is that the change onto another thread takes a short amount of time. And that causes the event to get lost. So staying on the same thread fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, is your code available on github somewhere? So far everything seems to be ok. Maybe it is an internal mosby bug. Is it working if you add `subscribeOn(schdulers.io())` to loadCardIntent() in presenters bind() method.
The only difference I see with or without `delay​()` is that your code runs sync (on main UI thread) whereas `delay()` switches the execution of your code to a background thread. Are you sure your interactor.getCardInfo() is meant to run on androids main UI thread? I.e. if it runs on main thread, but you are doing a http request (on main UI thread) an exception is thrown. Do you catch exceptions in interactor?

Comment: I tried it with `Schedulers.io()`. The behavior doesn't change. My assumption is that it is not necessarily a bug with mosby, but either a bug in rxjava or a time problem with the threads?

Comment: No I think the issue is that Observale.just()  (in your interactor) is eager and really did just fire onNext() when Mosby composes the observable chain internally. I think it will work you if you use Observable.fromCallable() or Observable.defer() in your Interactor instead of Observable.just(). Could you try it with Observable.fromCallable() please?

Comment: I changed it to `Observable.fromCallable(() -> new CardViewState.CardFrontState(CARDS[cardInfo.card]));`. Unfortunately it doesn't change the behavior. Could it be a problem with the `merge()` transforming the Observable into a PublishSubject, like the problem explained [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/177) (not related to android/rxjava)?

Comment: Not, sure, I will setup a sample project over the weekend to reproduce it. I will come back to you next week.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This was a mosby internal issue and has been fixed now.

See https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues/242

Please use latest snapshot:

`com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvi:3.0.4-SNAPSHOT`

(see [README](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby#dependency)) to verify everything works now as intended.

Please comment on the linked github issue if it fixes your problem or not.
Thanks.